# There is an error in debugging the file in vscode.How can i solve this problem?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

There is no problem with vscode running the file directly, but if there is an error in debugging the file [WinError 3] the system cannot find the specified path. : '../image/ocean_input/', as shown in the figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo66j.png)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide more information. What file? Screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Note the **current working directory** of your running `python` process.

- When you run directly, you *may* mean `python main.py`, which the `pwd` is `[some long text]/implement`, thus `../image/ocean_input` is correct.
- When you are debugging, you *may* run `python` under project root directory, which make `../image` looking for something else, thus not found.

Comment: How can I this problem?

Comment: @tjx you need to configure the cwd for when you run your program.

Comment: Yes.I implement this method!But it isn't good!As follows!

Comment: {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }